# expanding x axis to accomodate same data for different scenarios

Tags: python, r, data-visualization

Is there a way in R (python suggestions are also fine) to accomodate several graphs in one. Not exactly placing two different subplots in one figure with the par function, but sort of "gluing" additional set of data by extending the x axis? In my case x axis stands for years, so I want to plot different scenarions (y axis) for the same years.

this is what I want

[image: this is what I want]

Thanks!

UPD.: solved this by removing everything related to y-axes when plotting Model 2 and then combined plot 1 and plot 2 in a grid using `grid.arrange`

Comment: Do you mean to show three lines in the same plot (red, blue, dotted in your example), or two charts (with the same x-axes) side by side (in your example each chart would be each "Model")? Or is it that you don't want to show a separate Y-axis for each subplot essentially?

Comment: @tania, if I understand you correctly, I need both, i.e. each Model (estimation technique) has three different scenarios. The charts(model) need to be side by side, but they share the same y axis. It is as if I first plot three scenarios of Model 1, then 3 scenarios of Model two, and "attach" the second plot to the first one, 'cause they share the same y -axis, and for x -axis I'd like each model to have sepate set of ticks on the x-axes (2020, 2030, 2050)

Comment: I suspect the way to do this in base graphics is to calculate the x positions manually, and then relabel the x-axis. As an alternative, the `ggplot2` function `facet_wrap` could create something naturally that is almost what you describe, see the [third example here](https://plotly.com/ggplot2/facet_wrap/)

Answer (score 0):

as an easier way, I suggest you `patchwork` library for R. (so you can do it with just one character)

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

x <- 1970:2009

y1 <- sample(150:220,40)

y2 <- sample(180:600,40)

y3 <- sample(250:300,40)

y4 <- sample(150:220,40)

y5 <- sample(180:600,40)

y6 <- sample(250:300,40)

df <- data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3)


plot1 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x=x))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y1, color="blue"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y2, color="red"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y3, color="orange"))

plot2 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x=x))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y4, color="blue"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y5, color="red"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y6, color="orange"))


plot1+plot2
```